# How to calculate the angle of tilt for a cylinder hanging from two hooks known distance apart with strings of unequal length?

Tags: geometry, simulation, physics, trigonometry

I'm making a wall plotter that hangs on a wall by two belts and uses stepper motors to accurately and precisely control the lengths of those belts. I'm having trouble figuring out how to calculate the length of belts needed so that the device lands on a given coordinate X,Y . Let's restate the problem to make it simpler:

You have a perfectly vertical wall and two hooks on a horizontal line, distance D apart. You have a metal cylinder of length C. The left end of the cylinder is attached to the left hook with a string of length L, and the right end of the cylinder is attached to the right hook with a string of length R. I need to figure out how to calculate L and R so the middle of the cylinder lands on a given point (X,Y). We can assume that the strings themselves weigh nothing, but the cylinder has weight and is affected by gravity.

If X == D / 2, or in other words the given point is in the middle between the hooks, L and R are the same length and the cylinder is perfectly horizontal. However, the farther the point is from the middle, the more the cylinder is going to tilt: clockwise if the point is to the left of the middle axis, and ccw if it's to the right. I initially assumed that the angle of tilt is the same as the angle of deviation from the vertical middle axis: I calculate the angle formed by a vertical line through D / 2 and a line from (D / 2, 0) to (X,Y), but that still produces a slightly warped drawing.

I realize that things like center of gravity of the cylinder (and more relevantly, the plotter) affect the tilt, but the approximation would be good enough if we can assume that the weight is uniformly distributed. Beyond that, as far as I can tell, the actual weight doesn't matter, but I'm also not certain of that.

How would I go about better approximating this angle of tilt? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry. How is this question related to programming?

Comment: this is physics (kinematics) problem instead of programming one. I think your problem is you forget to take into account that your "strings" (hope they are solid belts/ropes instead of real string) are affected just by radial part of gravity force from the cylinder as axial part is negated by the "string" itself (but if its really a string then axial part will affect its length) ... so the more the cylinder is tilted the more the lower side will tend to rotate the whole thing to the side (so the center of cylinder will also move to side not just tilt more)

Comment: also with tilt the angles between cylinder and left and right "string" will not be equal so the radial part will have different ratios which will add its part to the whole rotation and side moving. So in a nutshell you can not compute this just as geometrical problem ... but find equalized state where all forces are canceling each other ...

Comment: You're both absolutely right - this is more a geometry / physics question, than programming. Thank you for your input. I'll draw it out with force vectors and see how that comes out.